# Weird ClassCastException with Jetty 9 and Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, jetty

I'm trying to migrate some of my applications using spring from Tomcat 8 to Jetty 9 as centrally not embedded however I'm getting weird exception whenever it looks up jndi datasource.

Here's some stack trace, http://pastebin.com/wZKEcChL

No matter what I do like configuring in jetty.xml or jetty-web.xml it ends up same.

Here's an example datasource configuration:

```xml
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource" id="IST2DB">
    <Arg>jdbc/IST2DB</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClass">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://blahblah</Set>
            <Set name="user">user</Set>
            <Set name="password">pass</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

And here how I look up jndi from spring configuration (pretty much straightforward)

```xml
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ist2dbxa" jndi-name="jdbc/IST2DB"/>
```

I've even tried writing a datasource wrapper as following (which should be calling same thing in the end but it doesn't hurt to try) but no use.

```
public class DataSource implements javax.sql.DataSource {

    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource() throws NamingException {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/IST2DB");
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.unwrap(iface);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface) throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.isWrapperFor(iface);
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getLogWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter out) throws SQLException {
        dataSource.setLogWriter(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLoginTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {
        dataSource.setLoginTimeout(seconds);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getLoginTimeout();
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
        return dataSource.getParentLogger();
    }

}
```

I don't know if it has to do with jetty or spring but programmatically lookups from jetty just works fine.

Comment: have you tried adding an empty arg as your first argument of the jetty resource? If I remember correctly the first argument was the scope of your resource.

Comment: @Qkyrie is right. [Jetty docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-jetty-jndi.html#defining-jndi-naming-entries)

Comment: yup, already tried that but no use.

Comment: Don't put stacktraces on external services, copy them into your question

Comment: Where is your spring jars, c3p0 jars, and mysql jars? as you are potentially crossing the WebAppClassloader isolation if done improperly.  Mostly interested in location (server vs webapp).

Comment: Well I wanted to include some debug information from server in case it would come in handy and apparently it was exceeding question limit. Anyhow, relevant connection pooling jars are located in ext folder and activated via ext module which is recommended way I suppose and others are all on application side which is managed by maven.